Rigging Grease Pencil strokes to Character Armature
Is there a better way to rig stoke lines from grease pencil to a character rig for a model? I'm working on a model that I want to use grease pencil lines with, but I don't know how to go about rigging them or having them follow the bones? So far I've seen methods to parent strokes to bone but I can't parent them to individual bones, same with the GP armature modifier and vertex groups but I can't select individual bones in the modifier.
So far what I'm doing is separating the stokes to individual GP objects and parenting them. I know this is probably extremely inefficient but I'm not sure what else to try.


